# Why does a pod with one container of equal requests and limits classify as a Burstable pod?

Tags: kubernetes

In the [kubernetes documentation here](https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/node/resource-qos.md#qos-classes) the conditions for a pod that is classified as `Burstable` in regards to resource QOS is defined as

> If requests and optionally limits are set (not equal to 0) for one or
>   more resources across one or more containers, and they are not equal,
>   then the pod is classified as Burstable. When limits are not
>   specified, they default to the node capacity.

so basically stated differently:

1. `requests` set for **one or more** resources (cpu/memory) across **one or more** containers in the pod.
2. `limits` are optional: if set, they should be **not be equal** to the `requests` of the same
   resource.

But then later on the documentation gives the following as an example of `Burstable` pod:

```
containers:
  name: foo
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: 10m
        memory: 1Gi
      requests:
        cpu: 10m
        memory: 1Gi

  name: bar
```

*Note:* Container `bar` has no resources specified.

This example fulfils condition 1. However, it doesn't satisfy condition 2, since the limits and requests are  set for one container but they are **equal**.

So why is this pod classified as a `Burstable` pod?

K8s documentation containing QOS explanation and examples: https://github.com/kubernetes/community/blob/master/contributors/design-proposals/node/resource-qos.md#qos-classes

Comment: The k8s documentation link mentioned in the post seems broken. And, I believe this is the updated link - https://github.com/kubernetes/design-proposals-archive/blob/main/node/resource-qos.md#qos-classes

Answer (score 5):

The evaluation of the **Quality of Service (QoS)** is done by scheduler on the **whole** pod, i.e. container by container and then taking the lowest evaluation.

Take a look at this example:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: class
spec:
  containers:
  - name: container1
    image: busybox
    command: ["sh"]
    args: ["-c","sleep 3600"]
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: 100Mi
        cpu: 200m
      limits:
        memory: 100Mi
        cpu: 200m
  - name: container2
    image: busybox
    command: ["sh"]
    args: ["-c","sleep 3600"]
    resources:
      requests:
        memory: 100Mi
        cpu: 200m
```

`container1` has Guaranteed QoS, because it has both requests and limits defined, and they are equals.

`container2` has Burstable QoS, because it hasn't limits defined, but only requests.

class pod is evaluated, based on both containers and taking the lowest evaluation:

```
min(Guaranteed, Burstable) = Burstable
```

Reference: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/quality-service-pod/

Comment: Is there a reference to where the scheduler works this way to evaluate the pod QOS? could you please add give a link?

Also, in my example the container `bar` should classify as a `Best Effort`, since it doesn't have resources specified. So with your explanation of how the k8s schedular works, shouldn't then this pod be classified as a `Best Effort` pod, but not `Burstable`.

Comment: But then my example (k8s documentation) should be `Best Effort` and not `Burstable`, right? 

Also, I don't see it  written explicitly in this reference, that it works that way: gets the minimum QOS of containers in the pod.

Comment: In your example you missed writing the definition of the second container, so I cannot say anything. You can use my example and change the values and/or omit some request/limit section and see what happens.

Comment: No, I didn't miss writing definition for the second container. It's a container with no resources defined, exactly copied from the example by the documentation I linked by kubernetes.

Comment: please write the link you used.

Comment: Sorry, it wasn't clearly shown before. Now I made it more explicit.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174496/discussion-between-nicola-benaglia-and-hesham-massoud).